# NCurses "mvwaddch" Clarification Needed

Tags: c++, ncurses

I have been wrestling with the nuances of ncurses windows all day and I've finally been stumped. I have an array `map[x][y]` filled with random integers. The idea is to print the array into the window using the `for` loop. I've changed the location of everything in the `while` loop *many* times.

To test whether `mvwaddch` was working I added a test line of code: `mvwaddch(main_window,10,10,'B');`

This causes 'B' to display in the window at (10,10). But only after pressing a key. **Why is this?**

Since this works, I have become completely baffled as to why my `map` isn't printing. **How can I print my map?**

**EDIT: FULL CODE**

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    // Curses Initialization
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr,TRUE);

    // Main Variables
    int inpt;
    int playing = true;

    // Map Variables
    srand(1);
    int mapWidth = 80;
    int mapHeight = 20;
    int map[mapWidth][mapHeight];

    // Window Initialization
    WINDOW *main_window;
    int wheight = LINES;
    int wwidth = COLS;
    main_window = newwin(wheight,wwidth,0,0);
    wborder(main_window, '|', '|', '-', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*');

    // Build Map
    for(int x=0; x>=mapWidth; x++){
        for(int y=0; y>=mapHeight; y++){
            map[mapWidth][mapHeight] = floor(rand() % 11 + 1);
        }
    }

**END EDIT**


    while(playing) {
        inpt = wgetch(main_window);
        wrefresh(main_window);
    
        mvwaddch(main_window,10,10,'B');    
    
        // Draw Map
        for(int y=1; y>=mapHeight-1; y++){
            for(int x=1; x>=mapWidth-1; x++){
                mvwaddch(main_window,x,y,map[x][y]);
            }   
        }   

       if (inpt == 'q'){
        endwin();
        playing = false;
       }   
       if (inpt == KEY_RESIZE){
        wclear(main_window);
        wborder(main_window, '|', '|', '-', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*');    
        wrefresh(main_window);
       }

    }
```

> As a sidenote, the window border is working well, with the border resizing to the screen properly. This was another tricky method to iron out if anyone ever is searching.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the rest of the loop, this part

```
inpt = wgetch(main_window);
wrefresh(main_window);

mvwaddch(main_window,10,10,'B');
```

does a refresh as part of `wgetch`, then an unnecessary refresh, and then adds a character — which will be painted on the next refresh (i.e., when it loops back to `wgetch`).

Comment: This fixed the problem of `B` writing only after a keypress. The map still is not drawing. Any suggestions?

Comment: The program's incomplete, and I don't know whether you've used cbreak and/or keypad (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/base/lib_getch.c)).

Comment: I've updated the include the full code. I can not understand the source of ncurses whatsoever.